# How to display local notifications with iOS on Flutter application?

Tags: ios, notifications, flutter, viewcontroller

I'm working on a Flutter application. I'm trying to display local notification in background. I know it's not possible to run dart code in background currently. So I'm trying to display these notifications with iOS. To display these notifications, I have to create a new ViewController but when I launch my Flutter app, the ViewController of Flutter is running but not the one on the iOS side.

I'm new to iOS development. 
Is there a solution to run two ViewController? Is there another solution to launch my local notification?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plugin for the job

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications

In case you wish to implement notifications yourself, you would have to write a [plugin](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#plugin), or use [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

Implementation of those are out of the scope of the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19794345)

Comment: It is a little tricky, as any details would just copy paste content from the link, and link on pub.dartlang.org (packages) are permanent and they cannot be deleted.

Comment: I tried to use the plugin flutter_local_notifications but I have this exception: `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel dexterous.com/flutter/local_notifications)`. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: yes, run flutter clean from the console, and start again